offline voice recognition for Arabic Language in flutter?
I am using speech_to_text and it's very good online
, but i want it work offline how to make this in Flutter?
according to readme file of package
in google App

install google app

Settings > Voice > Languages - select the language

Settings > Voice > Languages > Offline speech recognition - install language

Settings > Language and region - select the Search language and Search region

Delete the build folder from the root path of the project and run again


I didn't found Arabic language to make it offline.
How to install offline speech recognition, Thanks in advance.

You know how to install it. You've documented all the steps. If the Arabic language isn't available, there's nothing anyone here can do about it. Have you contacted Google?

You can try VOSK: https://alphacephei.com/vosk. I used this library in Python and Java. There are two arabic models there: 318 Mb and 1.3 Gb.

If your requirement is only for android, You can use flutter_deep_speech package, which is plugin for speech recognition and transcription using Mozilla's DeepSpeech.
You will have to load a tensor-flow lite DeepSpeech model through asset folder, Which in-turn helps you to do transcription offline.
If you can't find a tflite model for arabic, You can refer this to convert one.
